# Ubuntu 22.04 second monitor scaling size issue

Tags: 22.04, external-monitor

I have a Lenovo Yoga Pro 7 with Ubuntu 22.04. When I use the external monitor (HP 24'' fullHD) I have some serious issue with the size: basically if it's good the external monitor (which I want as primary one) the built in is too small, if it's good the built in the external one everything is too big. I tried all different combos of scaling factor. Ideas?

Comment: You need to use Wayland to have different scaling factors. Otherwise you will need to lower the resolution of one, which causes blurriness